# Aligning Two Columns of Divs Regardless of Div Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem where I have a ton of divs all varying in height, and I want them to align vertically in two columns. I understand why it's breaking if the first div is longer than the second, but I can't think of a solution for it.

HTML:

```
 <div class="board-container">
      <div class="board-card">
            <h1>CARD #1</h1>
            <h2>ODD</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here.</p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #2</h1>
        <h2>EVEN</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. </p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #3</h1>
        <h2>ODD</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. </p>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #4</h1>
        <h2>EVEN</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text.And even more text. And even more text.  </p>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.board-card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.board-card:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.board-card:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.board-card h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #d85656;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.board-card h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 15px;
}

.board-card h1, .board-card h2 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}

.board-card-desc p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.board-card-desc {
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.board-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Here it is in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4mu8eg6/1/). As you can see, if the second card is short than the first, the third card breaks out of line. Is there a good solution to make each odd and even child align to the left and right respectively, regardless of height of the card?

Answer (score 1):

You could get pretty far with this by replacing `.board-container`'s css with [CSS column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts):

```
.board-container {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```css
.board-card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.board-card h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #d85656;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.board-card h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 15px;
}

.board-card h1, .board-card h2 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}

.board-card-desc p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.board-card-desc {
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.board-container {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="board-container">
  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #1</h1>
        <h2>ODD</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here. A ton of text here.</p>
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #2</h1>
        <h2>EVEN</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. </p>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #3</h1>
        <h2>ODD</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. More text here. </p>
        </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="board-card">
        <h1>CARD #4</h1>
        <h2>EVEN</h2>

        <div class="board-card-desc">
          <p> And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text. And even more text.And even more text. And even more text.  </p>
        </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using flexbox?

https://jsfiddle.net/d4mu8eg6/2/

```
.board-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I didn't think of that, but I also don't want the boxes to be the same height. I'd rather see each box be its own height.

Comment: Note, you can also use CSS Grid for this.

Comment: easiest here is column css  https://jsfiddle.net/d4mu8eg6/6/ or the masonry script for  abetter and most solid layout https://masonry.desandro.com/   Flex will require a set height to wrap content to next column , grid will require spanning rows . grid and flex are not made to draw columns of differents heights item naturally.